# Difference between hover syntaxes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the difference between these two different hover selector syntaxes?

```
#id:hover p 
#id p:hover
```

Comment: Have you googled your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#id:hover p` - will select a descendant `p` element when hovering over the parent `#id` element.

`#id p:hover` - will select a descendant `p` element (a descendant of an `#id` element) when it is being hovered over.

Take this for example:

```css
.example1:hover p,
.example2 p:hover {
  color: red;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
div p {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <p>.example1:hover p</p>
  <p>The p element is styled when hovering over the parent.</p>
</div>

<div class="example2">
  <p>.example2 p:hover</p>
  <p>The p element is styled when hovering over the p element</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`id:hover p` will select the `p` element inside of the element `id` when the `id` gets hovered.

`id p:hover` will select the `p` element inside of the element `id` when the `p` gets hovered.

Often the result is the same but nethertheless it is a difference of which element is hovered.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them select the `p` element which is a child or descendant of an element with `id='id'` but the difference lies in when it gets selected **and** the no. of elements that get selected.

- `#id:hover p` - Here the `p` gets selected when the element with `id='id'` is hovered on (the parent or grandparent is hovered). This will **select all the descendant `p` tags**.
- `#id p:hover` - Here the `p` gets selected when the `p` itself is hovered (and not the parent or grandparent). This will **select only the `p` which is being hovered on**.

As you can see in the below snippet, hovering on the `p` tag itself (the text *Child para* or *Descendant para*) will change the text `color` to `beige` only for the `p` which is actually being hovered whereas hovering on the other parts (which is the parent) would change the `background` of all descendant `p` to `red`.

You would also notice that hovering on the `p` tag also causes its `background` to get changed to red. This is because when `p` is hovered on, the parent/grandparent is also getting hovered on implicitly.

```css
#id:hover p {
  background: red;
}
#id p:hover {
  color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div id='id'>
  Some content
  <p>Child para</p>
  <p>Child para</p>
</div>
<div id='id'>
  Some content (grandparent)
  <div> Some content (parent)
    <p>Descendant para</p>
    <p>Descendant para</p>
  </div>
</div>
```